# ...to be liable to be/being

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between the following structures:

> Power is liable to be abused.

Although I cannot find the sentence of

Power is liable to being abused.

I can find some other sentences in which "liable to being" was used.

For example

> Swimming animals are liable to being hit by boats.

I can feel that the word power as a subject is something affects something else. However, the sentence is passive voice. On the other hand, the word animals are object affected by action in terms of meaning.

So I am confused when should I use "...liable to be V3..." and "...liable to being V3..."

EDIT :

From [Google Ngram results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=liable%20to%20be%20*%2Cliable%20to%20being%20*&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cliable%20to%20be%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20be%20called%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20be%20affected%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20be%20punished%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20be%20sued%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20be%20attacked%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20be%20taken%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20be%20mistaken%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20be%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20be%20broken%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20be%20misunderstood%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cliable%20to%20being%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20being%20too%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20being%20taken%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20being%20misunderstood%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20being%20killed%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bliable%20to%20being%20called%3B%2Cc0) I can see for some verbs both form is used such as " liable to be called/ being called" or "liable to be taken/being taken".

Answer (score -1):

**Liable to** is a phrase meaning something is likely to happen, where **to** is a preposition, *not* part of the infinitive **to be**. So here you should always you **being** instead of **be** because you need to form a gerund phrase. Thus the first sentence you have is wrong and should read, "Power is liable to being abused." [Here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-being-vs-to-be.158879/) are some other examples of the same issue.

Comment: Be careful with the word **always**: _The picnic is liable to be spoiled by rain. Violators are liable to be punished with imprisonment and fine. They are liable to be dealt with by the police under public order and criminal legislation._

Comment: I would say those are all incorrect as well. A lot of people misuse this phrase, perhaps.

Comment: google "liable to be" - ablout 36M of those "incorrect" )))

Comment: Explain how it's correct. How can you use the infinitive form without "to"? The "to" here is a preposition.

Comment: Ever heard about a [bare infinitive](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/)?

Comment: I think the OP's version is correct and your version is wrong. I know I would say, "Power is liable to be abused" (not "to being abused"). [Check out the ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+liable+to+be%2Cis+liable+to+being&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: I can find both ways in books. I don't know why I prefer the first, then, except you would say, "The president's power is being abused."

Comment: I'm liable to disagree with you and downvote. If you've got several native speakers telling you *"liable to + base form"* is correct, and there's [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=liable+to+be%2Cliable+to+being&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cliable%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cliable%20to%20being%3B%2Cc0) that suggests pretty much nobody ever uses "liable to" + being.